# при запуске кода, frame не показывает

Tags: java, swing

пишу код секундомера с кнопками.
на синтаксис нигде не ругается, все написано верно, перепроверено десятки раз, но фрейм все равно не показывает. в консоли показывает, что программа запущена, но ничего нет.

```html
package stopwatch;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stopwatch implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton startButton = new JButton("СТАРТ");
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("СБРОС");
    JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
    int elapsedTime = 0;
    int seconds =0;
    int minutes =0;
    int hours=0;
    boolean started = false;
    String seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
    String minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
    String hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
    
    void StopWatch(){
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: попробовал другой код с фреймами(код нашёл на этом сайте), все работает, значит проблема не в софте.

Comment: Для показа данного фрейма должен выполниться ваш метод `StopWatch`, но в данном коде не видно, где и как он вызывается.  Вероятно, этот вызов следует прописать в методе `actionPerformed`, и соответственно экземпляр данного класса, реализующего `ActionListener`, должен быть назначен какому-то компоненту типа кнопки